# Spring Boot and Teradata UnsatisfiedDependencyException

Tags: java, spring, teradata

I am trying to create a simple Spring application with Teradata database.

It was working with mySql database and driver but after changing to Teradata driver/databased  i receive following exception :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL must start with 'jdbc'
```

Application Properties :

```
spring.datasource.url =jdbc:teradata://servername/db
spring.datasource.username = dbc
spring.datasource.password = dbc
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.ncr.teradata.TeraDriver
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is problem of Spring you might be using `@Autowire` on constructor but spring can't inject class with that name. To solve the problem, just define a `DataSource` in your context - at which point Spring will be able to inject the bean and correctly bootstrap the context.